# "No argument given" when inheriting from a class

Tags: c#

Unity uses an older version of C#, so we don't have a builtin `Tuple` class. I have the following definition that I basically copied from somewhere on the internet, unfortunately I don't remember where:

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 First { get; private set; }
    public T2 Second { get; private set; }
    internal Tuple(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}

public static class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> New<T1, T2>(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        var tuple = new Tuple<T1, T2>(first, second);
        return tuple;
    }
}
```

That's fine, it works for my needs.

However now I have a script which needs to refer to a specific Tuple type many times, and I want to 'alias' that type:

```
 public class RequiredField : Tuple<Type, MonoBehaviour>{}
```

I want `RequiredField` to basically be an alias for `Tuple<Type, MonoBehaviour>`.

This is giving me an error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'first' of 'Tuple.Tuple(Type, MonoBehaviour)' (CS7036) [Assembly-CSharp]

I sort of know the bare-minimum amount of C# needed to do basic Unity programming ... unfortunately that means I am ill-equipped to debug errors like this.

Can anyone point in the direction of how to fix this?

Comment: Constructor. Your derived class has not a constructor with the proper arguments. Note however that it will be almost useless because a tuple created with the static method won't be of the derived type.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti a little embarassing, but I don't actually know how to make the constructor. I've managed to get this far without that skill, believe it or not. But I will try. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused about the purpose of the `New` method. Why not just call the constructor "directly" instead?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I have no idea. Like I mentioned I just got that code from somewhere :/

Comment: See updated comment, even with a ctor it won't behave the way you'd like (unless you add also another overload for Tuple.New()) because a derived class isn't just a specialised generic or a `typedef`

Comment: @ejoshuas I guess because generic type arguments are deducted from the parameters and you do not need to specify them

Comment: Ok thank you guys. I think I may have solved it. I will just make my own answer I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of version of Unity you are using, but it has been supporting .Net4.x for quite a while now. 
If it is not set for you project, then you can set it under `Project Settings` -> `Player` -> `Scripting Runtime Version`. 
Set it to `.Net 4.x Equivalent` and you can use Tuples from the `System` namespace.

[image: project settings]

Here an image as proof.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following code got it done

```
public class RequiredField : Tuple<Type, MonoBehaviour>{
    public RequiredField(Type type, MonoBehaviour obj) : base(type, obj) {}
}
```